# Is it necessary to Wait when using TPL for multi-threading in ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, task-parallel-library

I have the following code in my ASP.Net Webforms code-behind in a button click event. There are quite a few other events on the page.

Question is: **If Method2 takes longer that the Page life cycle to complete, will my Page life cycle complete and send its html output to the browser? If yes, then what would be the best way to handle this situation - either send updates to UI ( which I have no clue about) or always use Tasks.WaitAll in this situation?**

So, when user sees the web form in his/her browser, the thread running Method2 is still in progress. Please note that I have commented out the code that waits for all tasks to complete.

```
       Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Method1(); 
                    success1 = true;
                }
                catch (Exception e4)
                {
                    success1 = false;
                    ex = e4.ToString();
                }
            }),
          Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Method2();
                        success2 = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e5)
                    {
                        success2 = false;
                        ex = e5.ToString();
                    }
                })

        };
   //Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If Method2 takes longer that the Page life cycle to complete, will my Page life cycle complete and send its html output to the browser?

Yes.

You'll need to ensure that the handler does not finish execution before you are ready for ASP to move on and continue with the page lifecycle process.

You should also avoid the manipulation of shared memory between threads, as you are not doing so in a safe manor.

Rather than setting a `success` boolean, you can simply cut out all of that code.  You can let the exception bubble up and have the main thread check to see that neither task threw an exception instead.  When doing that, the TPL will ensure proper synchronization of the data shared between threads.

Comment: Isn't there a way for long running thread to send updates to WebForm UI, or that would be a complex implementation even if it was possible?

Comment: @Sunil Not naively in ASP.  You'd need to create a web socket or something analogous to be able to do that.  That doesn't just come for free, you need to set all of that up.

Comment: So, I think the best approach may be to declare the Task[] array and the success flags for each thread as private variables in Web Form and then in the last event i.e. PreRender, wait for the tasks by using Tasks.WaitAll, so the page events code can run without waiting for tasks. Does this seem an optimal approach for my scenario?

Comment: @Sunil No.  First off, as I said before, you shouldn't even *have* success variables.  All of that data is exposed through the `Task` if you simply don't catch the exception.  Next, I wouldn't want to be running tasks across multiple stages of the life cycle.  I wouldn't expect that to be safe, at least unless you're never interacting with any aspect of the request/response until after the tasks complete, and from a state in which those changes should be made.  Even so, I'd avoid it unless it is truly necessary.

Comment: If do not set success flags at a thread/method level, then I will not know which thread/method caused an error. I want to finally update the Webform with a message that says Method1 succeeded, Method2 failed.

Comment: Without task based approach, my WebForm is taking 15 seconds to complete, but with tasks, it takes only 3 seconds. So there is an improvement with Task based code Vs without it, and that is the justification for using Task based approach.

Comment: @Sunil As I said in my answer, there is no need for your success and error variables to exist.  When you go to display the results of the task you can *ask the task directly* if it succeeded or failed, and if so, what the exception was, by inspecting the `IsFaulted` and `Exception` properties.  What you are doing is more work, less safe, and harder to maintain, understand, work with.

Comment: @Sunil I'm not suggesting that you not parallelize your code; I'm suggesting that you leverage the TPL for your error handling/reporting, rather than doing it yourself.

Comment: Ok. I get that part of exception handling. But the other part, where even though I see a big improvement in page performance, you still think I should use the non-task based code?

Comment: Ok. I get it now. Thanks for all your detailed comments.